# Scaling of variables considering the values of a single column or the whole dataset

Tags: python, normalization

I read many time that for machine learning and data mining algorithms the multi-dimensional input data should be scaled (e.g. normalized or standardized). Now my question is whether the average, min or max value shall be calculated for each row (variable) or for the dataset as a whole.

Let's say we have 3 variables

X=[x_1, x_2,.., x_n]

Y=[y_1, y_2,...,y_n]

Z= [z_1, z_2,...,z_n]

I use the following code in python

```
def standardize (data, train_split):
    data_mean = data[:train_split].mean(axis=0)
    data_std = data[:train_split].std(axis=0)
    return (data - data_mean)/ data_std


def normalize(data, train_split):
    data_max= data[:train_split].max(axis=0)
    data_min = data[:train_split].min(axis=0)
    return (data - data_min) / (data_max -  data_min)
```

If I saw it correctly, the code (that I copied from a tutorial) calculated the min,max, average and standarddeviation for the whole dataset. Meaning that the maxium value is the maxium of X,Y and Z. Is this correct to do or shall one only normalize and standardize a variable by considering its own values? So the min, max etc. should be calculated for every variable.

I'd appreciate every comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both can make sense depending on your data :

- Example 1 : if you have a feature that varies between -100 and -50 on the whole dataset you would want to normalize that column based on the values on the whole dataset
- Example 2 : if each sample is a list of values from different sensors and you only care about their relative values (for anomaly detection for instance) then you might want to normalize each sample

That being said, I think 9 times out of 10 you will want to normalize based on the statistics of the whole dataframe.

Note also that normalizing each sample based on the statistics of the whole dataset is an operation that can be reversed using the normalized data and the dataset statistics and therefore no information is lost : your data is basically the same but rescaled. A neural network could very well learn to reverse this operation.

Normalizing each sample based on this sample statistics can also be useful but this operation actually transforms the representation of your data. As an example, let's say you normalize each sample to a norm of 1, you can't recover the initial data without knowing the initial norm of that specific sample.

Comment: Thanks mprouveur for your answer (I upvoted it). I do not understand your first example. So when the values are between -100 and - 50 I should normalize based on the whole dataset? Why -100 and - 50? It is quite unlikely that the values are within these ranges? Or are you generally referring to variables with only negative values?

Comment: Well that depends on what type of algorithms you use. If you use regression/decision trees, scaling these values won't affect the model. However if you use a neural network, i will perform best if each feature given as input are within the same range, therefore it is quite common to scale them in the range [-1, +1]. In that sense if you have a feature that varies between -100 and -50 whereas your other features are within the "standard" range of [-1 +1], you will want to scale it down to [-1 ,+1].

Comment: Thanks mprouveur for your answer. Unfortunately I do not understand your last comment. Would you mind elaborating on that. Basically there are 2 questions: 1) When shall I standardize and when normalize? 2) When shall I use the whole dataset for normalizing or standardizing and when shall I only use the columns for doing that? I'd appreciate every further comment from you.

Comment: 1) When shall I standardize and when normalize? A good resource on the topic : https://medium.com/@dataakkadian/standardization-vs-normalization-da7a3a308c64 "Normalizing the data is sensitive to outliers, so if there are outliers in the data set it is a bad practice. Standardization creates a new data not bounded (unlike normalization)."

Comment: 2) When shall I use the whole dataset for normalizing or standardizing and when shall I only use the columns for doing that? By default I would standardize each column (instead of normalization because of outliers cf the link above), most algorithms perform better when each column of your dataset has a distribution similar to a a normal distribution. That's the default approach, however let's say that each row is the record of a sensor and each column is the value of that sensor at a specific timestamp : then it might (or not) make sense to standardize on each row instead of each column

Comment: As always in ML, trial and error is best to know what works best for you. Let me know if I am still not clear

Comment: Thanks mprouveur for your comment. In the answer you said that "9 times out of 10 you will want to normalize based on the statistics of the whole dataframe" and now you say that "By default I would standardize each column". Is this not contradicionary to the other statement?

Comment: In the answer you wrote: "A neural network could very well learn to reverse this operation." Why is this beneficial and how could the neural network do that? I'd appreciate any further comment

Comment: I meant the same thing when I mentionned normalizing on the whole dataset and normalizing each column. In both cased what I meant is that if you have 2 features like "price" and "area", you would usually standardize the price value on one hand and standardize the area value on the other

Comment: "A neural network could very well learn to reverse this operation." Normalization is a good thing, so it is unlikely that it would be beneficial for the neural network to learn to reverse it. What I mean to highlight is that no information is lost when you standardize each feature independently (price and area in the example above)

Comment: Thanks mprouveur for your comments. Unfortunately I do not undestand them and they sill confuse me. You wrote "I meant is that if you have 2 features like "price" and "area", you would usually standardize the price value on one hand and standardize the area value on the other"--> again my question: Shall I use the whole dataset or just one column to standardize them. This is basically the core question. I know that both of them should be standardized but they question is how?

Comment: You wrote "Normalization is a good thing, so it is unlikely that it would be beneficial for the neural network to learn to reverse it." That is the seconde quesiton. Shall I rather normalize or standardize the variables.

Comment: "Shall I use the whole dataset or just one column to standardize them." -> the default approach is to normalize/standardize each feature so that your algorithms sees features of roughly the same magnitude. In the example (price, area), you would process your data so that preprocessed_price = (price - average_price) / std_price and  preprocessed_area = (area - average_area) / std_area

Comment: "Shall I rather normalize or standardize the variables" -> normalizatoin using min and max values works well as long as you don't have outliers (abnormally high or low values), therefore it is more common to use standardization (-> https://medium.com/@dataakkadian/standardization-vs-normalization-da7a3a308c64)

Comment: Thanks mprouver. Above in your answer you stated "I think 9 times out of 10 you will want to normalize based on the statistics of the whole dataframe." whereas in your last comment - as far as I understood - you say that usually one should standardize/normalize based on the indiviudal variable (and not on the whole datafram)

Comment: Yes because I misunderstood your question, I thought you were wondering whether to normalize a sample based on this sample alone ( for example if you have an image, you may want to standardize each pixel based on all pixels of that one image) or whether to normalize each feature of that sample using the features of all samples (but by processing each feature individually as mentionned above with price and area)

Comment: Thanks mprouveur for your answers and effort. I really appreicate it. Bascially in the Python code above the features are standardized based on the whole data frame, right? The example is from an offical keras tutorial from their website (https://keras.io/examples/timeseries/timeseries_weather_forecasting/). So they are not doing what your suggestion would be as far as I understood.

Comment: You're welcome :). They actually are standardizing each column individually though it might not be obvious at first sight. They are normalizing each feature individually because `data[:train_split].mean(axis=0)` outputs a vector where each value is the mean of a feature. Same for `data[:train_split].std(axis=0)`, therefore the line `(data - data_mean) / data_std` will actually normalize each column based on each column's statistics.

Comment: Thanks mprouveur for your tremendous help. I accepted your answer.